# Nano does not resize to window size in bash on OS X

Tags: macos, bash, nano

Any ideas on how I can fix this? I am not sure what to google for =[

[image]

Comment: for me it does - i think you must have messed up your Terminal Settings - what version of os x do you use?

Comment: sorry didn't see you use iTerm before - i really never used iTerm sinze there is already a Terminal on Mac - i would guess it's a bug of iTerm or something with the iTerm Settings which prevents the resizing

Comment: ya, ill went in there for a little settings tuning, and bam, I have no idea which setting did it, and there were a lot I changed, new life rule, dont fix whats not broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a line in my `~/.bash_profile` (from Ubuntu) that might do the trick:

```
# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize
```

You can run this first in the Terminal window to see if it works, and if it does, add it to your own `~/.bash_profile`.

Alternatively, you could reset iTerm's preferences. With iTerm not running, move `~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist` to your Desktop (to back it up), and reopen iTerm. You'd have to replicate your old settings this way, but it might be easier to fix your problem in this way.